# Best method to sort a matrix in java based on column values

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, collections

I'm trying to sort a matrix based on the values in the column. Is there any in-built way to do this, like Arrays.sort() or even if I turned it into a List and then did Collections.sort().

If not, what is the best way to implement the sort function myself? (I would define best as something that doesn't take too long to implement but also doesn't have a very slow runtime).

For example, if I have:

```
int[][] matrix:

[0, 30]
[5, 10]
[15, 20]

I want to sort it to (the column values were sorted): 

[5, 10]
[15, 20]
[0, 30]

Another example:

int[][] matrix:

[7,10]
[2,4]

I want to sort it to (the column values were sorted):

[2,4]
[7,10]
```

Comment: so you are sorting rows by the 2nd column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do:

```
Arrays.sort(matrix, Comparator.comparingInt(row -> row[1]));
```

This sorts rows by its 2nd column and assumes each row has at least 2 columns.

It uses [`Arrays.sort`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort-T:A-java.util.Comparator-) and [`Comparator.comparingInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#comparingInt-java.util.function.ToIntFunction-) to extract the 2nd component of each row.

Answer (score 0):

```
Arrays.sort(matrix, Comparator.comparingInt(row -> row[1]));
```

where 1 is column to sort by.

It sorts your outer array (which contains arrays of data) with `Arrays.sort`. Values at a position [1] are compared in these rows to sort them properly. You can also compare by any other column, or row length, etc, like that:

```
 Arrays.sort(matrix, Comparator.comparingInt(row -> row.length));
```